# what type of products should be used to achieve the below mentioned functionality in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I want to implement the functionality in magento, the link of this is below :

http://ledflashingwatch.com/clocker-watch-illuminati-series/

when you click on strips, it changes strips image but when click on dial, it changes separately. And also add to cart will differentiate the product on these two values.

Can anyone advise me on how to proceed towards approaching this idea. And which type of products to use for this.

You can ask me questions if it's still not clear to you. And do tell me if it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available in Magento out of the box.
There are several possible approaches, but the user interface component will have to be custom built by you.

If you want the selected products to appear separately in the cart (like in the example you linked) choose simple products.

You could also use a grouped product with a custom interface.

If you want them to be added to the cart as a single product, but internally they are separate, use a configurable product. This is the option I personally would prefer.

You could also use a bundled product - It all depends what exactly you need.

I suggest first getting a good idea of the differences between the product types. Then study how they are reflected in the quote as quote items, i.e. visibility, parent and child items etc.

Once you know that, the implementation will be rather straight forward.
Build the UI. Build the request parameters for the add to cart call. Done.